# Using interrupts to strobe an LED

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, embedded, microprocessor

Beginner here, just playing around with a devboard using a PIC micro. I am attempting to strobe an LED using an interrupt, I've created the function below within isr.c, INTOSC is running at 4MHz, TMR0 at 1MHz with a 1:128 prescaler. Variables second and mSecond are defined as 100 in my initialize function; ledOnTime and ledOffTime are initialized at 0 in the same function; GP2 and GP4 are the pins tied to my LEDs as you can see from my comments.

First off, I've adjusted the timing of my interrupt occurrence based on my scope readings, the math I did beforehand had it happening too frequently so I slowed it down to where my pulses matched what I was looking for. I did the math backwards, and it still doesn't really add up in my mind. Maybe someone can give me a clue as to why.

Another thing I can't figure out is why when I increase either one of the the variables (second or mSecond) it increases the time in which my LEDs stay off.  What I'm trying to increase is the time they stay on. I would think based on the way I wrote it mSecond should do that, but from my results upon programming the micro it does not, and it has me baffled. Can someone please explain what's going on here:

```
if (TMR0IF){
    TMR0 += 162;                       // overflow 93 (at approx every 10 millisecs)
    TMR0IF = 0;                        // reset overflow flag

    if (ledOffTime == second){         // every second
        ledOffTime = 0;
        GP2 = 1;                       // turn lights on
        GP4 = 0;                       // bicolor led on
        if(ledOnTime == mSecond){      // every 100 millisecs
            ledOnTime = 0;             // reset on time count
            GP2 = 0;                   // turn lights off
            GP4 = 1;                   // bicolor led off
        }
        else{
            ledOnTime++;               // keep LEDs ON
        }
    }
    else{
        ledOffTime++;                  // keep LEDs OFF
    }
    system_ok = 1;
}
```

Found a solution, some variables and config registers changed:

- TMR0 prescaler 1:64
- SECOND = 440
- MSECOND = 40

  ```
  if (TMR0IF){
  TMR0 += 217;                         // approx 2.5 msecs
  TMR0IF = 0;                          //reset overflow flag

  if (++ledOffTime >= SECOND){         // Every second 
      ledOffTime = 0;                  // Clear off time count
      ledsOn = true;                   // LEDs are on
      GP4 = 0;                         // Bicolor LED
      GP2 = 0;                         // Turn LEDs on
  }
  if(ledsOn == true){                  
      if(++ledOnTime > MSECOND){   
          ledOnTime = 0;              // Reset on time count
          ledsOn = false;             // LEDs are off
          GP4 = 1;                    // Bicolor LED
          GP2 = 1;                    // LEDs are off
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: As listed, this isn't a function.

Comment: Can you provide a schematic for the circuit or a link to the device?  Are you sure the LEDs aren't wired in an active-low way?

Comment: Scott: What more do you need to see? It's doing something, that I can assure you of. So when you say it's not a "function" are you correcting my use of the word, or are you telling me this won't do anything? If you need to see additional code, just ask for that.

Moose: I unfortunately cannot provide a schematic, I believe GP4 is active low. Could I verify this somehow without having to show you the schematic?

Comment: @derkmcferk I'm trying to get the context of your code.  Interrupt flags get read and set, but this doesn't mean that the code you're posting is being handled as an INTERRUPT, which is a piece of code that gets run almost immediately when the interrupt gets tripped.    If your code is being treated as just an #include, it will certainly "do something", but then there can be all sorts of delays and other issues, depending on what else your code is doing.  Branching on the interrupt flag isn't quite the same thing as using the interrupt handler.

Comment: In many environments, you also need to enable the interrupt handler and the individual interrupts.  I think the interrupt flag might get set even if you don't do this, but the handler won't kick in.

Comment: By clearing `ledOffTime` on line 6, that means `ledOffTime` has to increment from 0 to `second` for every single increment of `ledOnTime`.  Was that your intention?  If instead you intended for `ledOffTIme` to count its cycle and then `ledOnTime` to count its complete cycle then you should clear `ledOffTime` at the same time you clear `ledOnTime`.

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand your code, but you've got the test for 100 milliseconds inside the block for the test for one second, so the only time the 100 millisecond test will be done is when the test for one second is true.

Comment: kkrambo & tcrosley: yes thank you guys, I realized before I saw your guys' comments there was no reason to have these the ledOnTime if statement nested in the first one.
Scott: I had the handler enabled, after some trial and error and going back through some of my configuration registers I realized I had not assigned the prescaler I had set to the TMR0 module so it was running at a different rate than original math had calculated.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution, some variables and config registers changed:

TMR0 prescaler 1:64
SECOND = 440
MSECOND = 40

```
if (TMR0IF){
TMR0 += 217;                         // approx 2.5 msecs
TMR0IF = 0;                          //reset overflow flag

    if (++ledOffTime >= SECOND){         // Every second 
        ledOffTime = 0;                  // Clear off time count
        ledsOn = true;                   // LEDs are on
        GP4 = 0;                         // Bicolor LED
        GP2 = 0;                         // Turn LEDs on
    }
    if(ledsOn == true){                  
        if(++ledOnTime > MSECOND){   
            ledOnTime = 0;              // Reset on time count
            ledsOn = false;             // LEDs are off
            GP4 = 1;                    // Bicolor LED
            GP2 = 1;                    // LEDs are off
        }
    }    
}
```